# Undefined variable: woocommerce_loop

Tags: loop, woocommerce-offtopic

Today I've updated my woocommerce plugin and get the following error on my website:

> Undefined variable: woocommerce_loop

My loop looks like (a slight modification of the **archive-product template** one year ago):

```
<?php
$newReleasesCounter = 0;
$loop = new WP_Query( $args_new_releases );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; 
    $woocommerce_loop['loop']++;?>

    <div id="<?php echo 'publication-'.$post->ID ?>" class="grid_4 txt-center product-preview">
        <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
    </div>

<?php 
$newReleasesCounter++;
endwhile; ?>
```

I have no idea what's wrong with this.

I would be grateful for any idea to solve this error.

Comment: You would get that warning if `$woocommerce_loop['loop']` were incremented without first being set, which it appears to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have updated WooCommerce to latest version, templates you have in your theme must have gone outdated. (Not sure which previous version you had on your website before updating it to latest version).

Please check WP Admin -> WooCommerce -> System Status -> at bottom there will be section named "Templates" there you can see what templates you have are outdated, and update your templates in theme to reflect latest changes.

I am not sure if above snippet is complete code of your custom archive-product.php or not, but its definitely different than latest WooCommerce archive-product.php template.

**And for the error you are seeing**

does your template have this code?

`global $product, $woocommerce_loop;`

at top of template file, if not **add it** and your error will go away, but I will suggest you use latest template from WooCommerce plugin and apply your customization's to it, to match your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your help Syed. I'll check the templates and let you know.

Comment: Removed `global $product; woocommerce_loop['loop']++;` inside the loop and added `global $product, woocommerce_loop;` it to the top of the file - seems to work. Thanks again.